# JPanel won't show in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a JPanel (non-resizable) showing a grid of buttons but when I try to add the JPanel to a JFrame it won't show.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
frame.setSize(681,920);
frame.setResizable(true);
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING,0,0));

JButton btn = new JButton();
btn.setContentAreaFilled( false );
btn.setBorder( null );
btn.setBounds(214,210,0,0);
label.add(btn);


panel.add(label);
frame.add(panel);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The output should be a resizable frame with inside a 3x4 grid of buttons.
If I don't use the panel and I put the line frame.setResizable(false) it works as expected but I need to add more stuff to the frame so I need to put the buttons safe in a panel.

Comment: BTW 1) `setLabel();` This method (which is not supplied) cannot be doing anything useful since it doesn't have a reference to the `JLabel label` 2) Why **is** the code attempting to add elements to a `JLabel`? I've only seen one reason for doing that, and even then there are better approaches. 3) `frame.setSize(681,920);` For a decorated frame, this is at best, a guess. 4) Change `panel.add(label);` to `panel.add(label); panel.setBackground(Color.RED);` to confirm the panel **is** visible. The problem is clearly elsewhere.

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry for the misunderstanding, actually setLabel() takes as parameter label and add many buttons on it. I don't get what you're trying to tell me at point 3).

Comment: I'll devote more time to explaining once you [edit] to add an MRE. BTW - *"setLabel() takes as parameter label"* This is one of the reasons we ask for an MRE. You're wasting your time (and more importantly, the time of people trying to help) by posting 'something like' the code used.

Comment: Thank you for 4) btw, the panel is visibile on frame. It won't show the label in it.

Comment: Why add the button to the label? JLabel overrides the preferred/min/max size method that focus on calculating the size of the label based on the text/icon properties

Answer (score 0):

Both panel and label are added to your frame, to make sure they are added write

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("JLABEL");
```

and

```
panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```